# How to get roleDefinitionId and roleDefinitionName details from Azure Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

When I am running below command:
az role assignment list --assignee AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA --all

I m getting below details associated to AppID AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
How I get this from Azure Graph?

```
{

"condition": null,

"conditionVersion": null,

"createdBy": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",

"createdOn": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",

"delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId": null,

"description": null,

"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/v4-westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dev-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

"name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

"principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

"principalName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

"principalType": "ServicePrincipal",

"resourceGroup": "westeurope",

"roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

"roleDefinitionName": "Reader",

"scope": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/v4-westeurope/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dev-vnet",

"type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran same **CLI command** in my environment, I got below response listing role assignments of application:

```
az role assignment list --assignee <spObjId> --all
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the **same results** from REST API, I generated access token using client credentials flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below Management API query by including access token, I got list of **role assignments** in response successfully like this:

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subId>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01&$filter=assignedTo('spObjId')
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Response:**
[List Azure role assignments using the REST API - Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest#list-role-assignments)

Comment: I want to get the list of roleDefinitionId and roleDefinitionName using AppId or SPId

Comment: I want Microsoft graph example to fetch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest

Comment: You can only list **Azure AD directory roles** using Microsoft Graph. For RBAC roles, you need to use **Azure Management API** as I mentioned in answer.